# Swift navigating between viewcontrollers

Tags: swift, objective-c, viewcontroller

Im looking for a word, method or similar for this situation. Say that i'm for example have 3 viewcontrollers, a, b and c.

And then i'm navigating from a to b and finally from b to c. From c then I want to dismiss my viewcontrollers all the way back to a. How do i achive this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller) you can use [popToRootViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller)

```
import UIKit

class AViewController: UIViewController {}
class BViewController: UIViewController {}
class CViewController: UIViewController {}

let a = AViewController()
let b = BViewController()
let c = CViewController()

let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: a)
nav.pushViewController(b, animated: true)
nav.pushViewController(c, animated: true)

// Option 1
nav.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

// Option 2
nav.popToViewController(a, animated: true)
```

Comment: Poptoviewcontroller Did the job I was looking for. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use `UINavigationController`:
From A -> B (this code in A):

```swift
navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerB(), animated: true)
```

From B -> C (this code in B):

```swift
navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerC(), animated: true)
```

From C -> A (this code in C):

```swift
navigatinoController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```